# Serde tag = x, but keep the tag in the struct

Tags: rust, serde

I'm trying to de-serialise JSON to a Rust struct with enum variants using internally tagged JSON (https://serde.rs/enum-representations.html).

I want to store the tag of the variant inside the struct - currently serde stores this data in attributes.

Can this be done keeping the tag key inside the struct?

The methods I have tried:

- A. `#[serde(untagged)]`

  - This works but I want to avoid it because of the performance hit of searching for a pattern match.
- B. `#[serde(tag = "f_tag")]`

  - This does not work and results in `` "duplicate field `f_tag`" ``.

    - Both the serde attribute and the enum variant rename try to use the same key.
  - I do not want to place `#[serde(rename = "f_tag")]` under `Uni` as this defines the tag key in the parent enum. (I want child structs to have the same tag key anywhere they are contained inside a parent enum).

Example:

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=584c3f32488a1a27f47dac9a0e81d31c

```rust
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};
use serde_json::json;
use serde_json::{Result, Value};

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
struct S1 {
    f1: String,
    f2: Uni,
}

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
#[serde(tag = "f_tag")]
// #[serde(untagged)]
enum Uni {
    String(String),

    // #[serde(rename = "f_tag")]
    S2(S2),

    // #[serde(rename = "f_tag")]
    S3(S3),
}

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
struct S2 {
    f_tag: S2Tag,
    f2_s2: bool,
}

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
struct S3 {
    f_tag: S3Tag,
    f2_s3: bool,
}

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
enum S2Tag {
    #[serde(rename = "s2")]
    S2,
}

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
enum S3Tag {
    #[serde(rename = "s3")]
    S3,
}

fn main() {
    let s1 = S1 {
        f1: "s1.f1".into(),
        f2: Uni::S2(S2 {
            f_tag: S2Tag::S2,
            f2_s2: true,
        }),
    };

    let j = serde_json::to_string(&s1).unwrap();
    dbg!(&j);

    let s1_2: S1 = serde_json::from_str(&j).unwrap();
    dbg!(s1_2);
}
```

```json
{
  "f1": "s1.f1",
  "f2": {
    // Issue: serde(tag = x) uses the name of the enum here.
    "f_tag": "S2",

    "f_tag": "s2",
    "f2_s2": true
  }
}
```

Comment: If `S2Tag` (etc) only has one variant, then you can use `#[serde(tag = "f_tag")]` along with `#[serde(skip_serializing)]` to get that behavior. Otherwise, I have a feeling you'll need to create a custom deserializer.

Comment: @vallentin This results in `missing field `f_tag` - it seems Serde takes the `f_tag` key and removes it after matching it to a variant, which leaves the struct missing a  `f_tag`.

Comment: I can add what I said as an answer. But it only works if the `S*Tag` enums only have 1 variant always.

Comment: Sure, or just a permalink to the edited playground code would be useful - thanks.

Comment: @nimast is this what you want? Wasn't sure what the duplicate keys in the JSON in the question were supposed to mean. https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=bdf1d66b8fa7543c2265415f8fb6df61

Comment: @drewtato Thanks for that. I'm not sure I understood your code. Here's what I'm after. Note it doesn't keep the tag value inside the object. https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=e6d058a631988a03c927eac98fb43d90

Comment: @nimast I think the key issue is that this question doesn't explain why the struct needs to have the `f_tag` field, since it's always going to be redundant information. Usually in Rust, you'd make a method that returns `&'static str` instead of occupying space in the struct. If you want to write a new clearer question then it would probably get more attention.

Comment: thanks @drewtato, at this point im looking for a solution to a technical problem. the reason is to be able to use it to search an array of such enum value and be able to differentiate, since u cant compare enum variants

Comment: @nimast You can compare enum variants. You can't make an array of `S2` and `S3` from this question. Perhaps this is what you're looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/q/55032236/6274355 Otherwise a new question would be best.