# How do I implement PartialEq for a type containing a function signature with a mutable reference?

Tags: types, rust

In my interpreter for a small toy language, I have an enum representing values:

```rust
#[derive(PartialEq)]
pub enum LangValue {
    Number(f64),
    String(String),
    // etc. etc.
    NativeFunction(FunctionMapping),
}
```

The `NativeFunction` type ties to calling Rust functions from within the language:

```rust
pub type NativeFuncSignature = fn(Vec<LangValue>) -> LangValue;

#[derive(PartialEq)]
pub struct NativeMapping {
    pub name: String,
    pub arg_count: usize,
    pub func: NativeFuncSignature,
}
```

I find myself needing to pass `NativeFuncSignature` a mutable reference to the struct which controls variables in the language, like this:

```rust
pub type NativeFuncSignature = fn(Vec<LangValue>, &mut Variables) -> LangValue;
```

This fails the `PartialEq` derivation for `NativeMapping`, but it's required because `LangValue` derives from `PartialEq` for checking if two values in the language are the same (numbers, strings, etc). It's worth noting I'm not really bothered whether comparisons between `NativeFunction`s are accurate, but it has to satisfy `PartialEq` in order for `LangValue` to.

How can I pass a `&mut` reference in a function signature while having it comply with `PartialEq`?

Comment: It looks like your question might be answered by the answers of [How to implement PartialEq for an enum?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36297412/155423). If not, please **[edit]** your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Comment: Specifically, *Sometimes, you want to implement the trait directly*.

Comment: It's hard to answer your question because it doesn't include a [MRE]. We can't tell what crates (and their versions), types, traits, fields, etc. are present in the code. It would make it easier for us to help you if you try to reproduce your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) if possible, otherwise in a brand new Cargo project, then [edit] your question to include the additional info. There are [Rust-specific MRE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) you can use to reduce your original code for posting here. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I think I’ve explained it in a convoluted way, I don’t have an issue with PartialEq on an enum, it’s an issue with PartialEq for a function type signature for which one of the arguments is an &mut reference. I’ll edit my question and include an example when I can get back to my computer.

Comment: That's not the point of the duplicate; please read beyond the title. The duplicate shows you how to implement `PartialEq` yourself when the `derive` version is insufficient.

Comment: Ah, my bad, sorry. I was glancing at it on mobile. When I get back to my machine I’ll double check that answer works and mark the question as a dupe if it does

Comment: Yes, thank you, that was the answer. I have flagged this question as a dupe, but I don't have enough rep to mark it definitively.